# Printing iframe blank when stylesheet added

Tags: html, css, iframe, printing

I have the following code so I can print some selected divs and it works fine except when I add a stylesheet I get a blank page.

```
var pri = document.getElementById("ifmcontentstoprint").contentWindow;
pri.document.open();
pri.document.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="utf-8"/><meta http-quiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><title>Print Frame</title><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost:10024/css/backend.css"/></head><body>' + content.innerHTML + '</body></html>');
pri.document.close();
pri.focus();
pri.print();
```

I've tried with a blank css just to make I wasn't hiding anything.

Comment: try to inspect your html page, and check for any error in console..

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason it was blank when adding css was due to the content not being loaded into the iframe when print was executed. Adding onload to the iframe resolved it.